# Playing mp3-Files from Swing with JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a Swing application and now I want to play some sound files. I think the best way (without using external libraries) it to use JavaFX.

So I tried to call a method from swing, but I'm stuck in various errors. Then I found a way to get no more errors, but it only plays the file for half a second.

```
public static void initBackgroundSound() {
    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {  
            String bip = "fox.mp3";
            Media media = new Media(new File(bip).toURI().toString());

            final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayerBuilder.create()
                .media(media).build();
            player.play();
        }
    });
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following code, I am able to play full length sound:

```
MediaPlayer player;
Media audioFile = new Media(new File("FILEPATH").toURI().toString());
player = new MediaPlayer(audioFile);
player.play();
```

Comment: Did you use `Platform.runLater` or did you just run these four lines by themselves?